# How do I use map function, so I can add the index as a property to the newly constructed object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of indexes: `selected = [2, 6, 10]` () for instance. I also have array of photo objects called `photos`. I want to keep track of only selected photos so I do :

```
const selectedPhotos = selectedArray.map((i) => photos[i]);
```

Which gives me the result:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "albumId": "someId1",
    "creationTime": "sometime",
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "name1.jpg",
    "id": "someId1",
    "uri": "someIUri1",
  },
  Object {
    "albumId": "someId2",
    "creationTime": "sometime",
    "duration": 0,
    "filename": "name2.jpg",
    "id": "id2",
    "uri": "uri2",
  },
  Object {
    "albumId": "someId3",
    "creationTime": "sometime",
    "filename": "filename3.jpg",
    "uri": "uri3",
  },
 ]
```

Which is good, **BUT** I also want to keep track of the selected index. So my question is, how should I add something like the following information: `index: 2`, or `index: 6`, etc alongside the `photo` properties. So I want to return something like:

```
Array [
      Object {
        "index": 2,
        "albumId": "someId1",
        "creationTime": "sometime",
        "duration": 0,
        "filename": "name1.jpg",
        "id": "someId1",
        "uri": "someIUri1",
      },
      Object {
        "index": 6
        "albumId": "someId2",
        "creationTime": "sometime",
        "duration": 0,
        "filename": "name2.jpg",
        "id": "id2",
        "uri": "uri2",
      },
      Object {
        "index": 10
        "albumId": "someId3",
        "creationTime": "sometime",
        "filename": "filename3.jpg",
        "uri": "uri3",
      },
     ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
const selectedPhotos = selectedArray.map((i) => {
 let curItem={...photos[i]};
 curItem.index=i;
  return curItem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the index:

```
const selectedPhotos = selectedArray.map((i) => {
  let photo = photos[i];
  photo.index = i;
  return photo;
});
```

Comment: I believe this is wrong as key here would be the array index and the desired value seems to be one inside the array.

Comment: You are correct, updated my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object and destructure the one you want inside of it, then add the index. That way you can do it in one line and it's easy to read.

```
const selectedPhotos = selectedArray.map(i => ({ ...photos[i], index: i }));
```

Safer version with [optional chaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
const selectedPhotos = selectedArray.map(i => ({ ...photos?.[i], index: i }));
```